# How to handle errors when using @ResponseBody in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using @ResponseBody for methods in controller. I am also using a HandlerInterceptorAdapter that calls database commit() in postHandle. If commit fails, I want the end user to know but by that time, it seems from the error message, the response has already been written. I am wondering how I should structure my code to achieve what I want. Of course, I don't want to write commit() in every controller method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use  below code and return our own error code back

```
       @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="No such Order")  // 404
            public class OrderNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
              // ...
             }
```